# one object is not rendering now

Tags: modeling, rendering

I went on and created my eye balls, then in the process of setting them I pressed <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to render to see what it looked like, only to see that my head is no longer showing up in Cycles Render.

What did I screw up now?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file?

Comment: @ShadyPuck yep it is in the mod post too.   [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1603" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1603/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check all of the *Ray Visibility:* settings under *Properties panel > Object tab > Cycles Settings dropdown*.

[image]

The fixed .blend file:

[image]

Comment: oh Ok, Yeah I was messing with that (i have no idea what its for setting) while following the how to make an eye. Must of messed it up then. Thanks I'll go check it now.

Comment: @uxserx-bw It's kind of like the _Light Path_ Node. There are different types of bounce rays, and this sets whether the object is visible to certain types. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.